# Error when run .js file with Node js "TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am writing a node program, but I meet an error when run following code (node test.js):

```
var pdf = require('html-pdf');
var options = {format: 'Letter'};
//console.log(" debug");
function Topdf(req,res) {
var info = require("./info.json");
res.render("./template.html",{ info : info,}, function (err, HTML) {
pdf.create(HTML, options).toFile('./downloads/employee.pdf', function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
        });
    }
})
})
}
Topdf();
```

**failed log:**

> res.render("./template.html",{ info : info,}, function (err, HTML) {
>
> ^
>     TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of undefined

Could anyone please help? What is problem here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you are defining a function with 2 parameters (which should not start with a capital letter, BTW, since it is not a function to be called as a constructor), the second one being `res`

```
function Topdf (req, res) {
    ...
}
```

But you are invoking it with no arguments:

```
Topdf();
```

So `req` and `res` are `undefined`, so you cannot read the property `render` of `undefined`. The error message is quite explicit...